# How do I change the way my form displays after it's been submitted?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, form, edit-form, display-form

I have a form that looks like this when the user fills it out:
[image: What list looks like when filling out]

But after it's been filled out, it displays like this:
[image: Filled out]

How do I get the filled out form to match the empty form?

I've tried making changes in SharePoint Designer, changing the Edit and Display forms, but that doesn't change anything.

Thanks.

Update:
[image: No column ordering]

Answer (score 0):

If you go into your list settings, there will be an option called Column Ordering listed under the columns of your list. If you click that, it will allow you to reorder the column layout of the forms.

Comment: Thank you, however there is no option for Column Ordering.  I've added an image above.  I'm working in 2010.  Thank you.

Comment: is this a content type?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Content Types, but I went to the advanced settings for the list, and under the Content Types, Yes is toggled.  So, I'm guessing that means it IS a Content Type? Thanks.